# Репозиторий не заливается на GitHub

Tags: github

> $ git push origin master fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git
>   repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Answer (score 5):

```
#Во-первых нужно проверить установлен ли origin
git remote -v
это покажет все push / fetch remotes в проекте
#Проверяем remote имя / адресс
$git remote -v
myOrigin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git (fetch)
myOrigin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git (push)

# Это не сработает т.к. `origin` не задан
$git push origin master

# Вам нужно использовать
$git push myOrigin master

#Если вы хотите переименовать или изменить URL, нужно удалить старый и добавить новый 
$git remote remove myOrigin

#Добавление отсутсвующего remote
$git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git

# Это будет работать как ожидалось
$git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Гит сам пишет Вам причину ошибки. У вас некорректно выставлены права на репозиторий ЛИБО ссылка на репозиторий неверна(соответственно репозитория нету).
Решение: создайте новый репозиторий и после через Гит залогиньтесь к новому репозиторию с нуля.

Comment: Необязательно. Достаточно было склонировать репозиторий себе, ведь я работаю на нескольких пк, а у меня всё хранилось в dropbox.